# How to make dynamic carousel with bootstrap 4 and aurelia

Tags: typescript, aurelia

i want to implement a dynamic carousel slider for sliding pictures. The pictures are coming from the backend, i have problems with making the carousel dynamic. It works fine with bootstrap 4 but for static and when i want it to integrate with aurelia it simply doesn't work.

```
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ul class="carousel-indicators" repeat.for="i of listOfImages.length">
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="i" class="${i==0 ? 'active': ''}"></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div repeat.for="image of listOfImages" class="carousel-item ${i==0 ? 'active': ''}">
          <img src.bind="image" style="width:1900px;height:700px;">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

The images dont show up and the carousel dont works at all. Any help ? Thank you very much

Comment: I think you should have repeat.for on `<li/>`, not ul?

Comment: okay so now the indicators of the carousel are rendered correctly but pictures are not showing and carousel is not working, its not going left or right and the pictures are no where.
@bigopon

Comment: you need to change `data-slide-to="i"` to `data-slide-to="${i}"` or `data-slide-to.bind="i"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work for you:

```
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo"  repeat.for="i of listOfImages.length" data-slide-to.bind="i" class="${$first ? 'active': ''}"></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div repeat.for="image of listOfImages" class="carousel-item ${$first ? 'active': ''}">
      <img src.bind="image" style="width:1900px;height:700px;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

explanation:

you currently have the letter `i` as plain text inside each of your `data-slide-to`.
you have the repeater on the wrong tag.
you can use `$first` to better reflect what you are trying to do.

using JQ to do this kind of job is against the mindset of MVVM.

Answer (score 1):

I am also stuck in this and mostly found bootstrap 3 code for this. That's why I merge all the code

1. We should have an array of images
2. Now Firstly we need to create an empty container in HTML

```html
  <div
    id="carouselExampleIndicators"
    class="carousel slide"
    data-ride="carousel"
  >
    <ol class="carousel-indicators"></ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner"></div>
    <a
      class="carousel-control-prev"
      href="#carouselExampleIndicators"
      role="button"
      data-slide="prev"
    >
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a
      class="carousel-control-next"
      href="#carouselExampleIndicators"
      role="button"
      data-slide="next"
    >
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

3. In the last step we need to add images in the above code

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
   var urls = []

        for (i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
          $(
            '<div class="carousel-item"><img src="' +
              urls[i] +
              '" class="d-block w-100">   </div>'
          ).appendTo(".carousel-inner");
          $(
            '<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="' +
              i +
              '"></li>'
          ).appendTo(".carousel-indicators");
        }

        $(".carousel-item").first().addClass("active");
        $(".carousel-indicators > li").first().addClass("active");
        $("#carouselExampleIndicators").carousel();
      });
```

4. just paste the above code by replacing the urls variable with your array of images

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with jQuery, on the next way.

```
<div ref="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="100">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators"></ol>
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner"></div>
      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="carousel-control-prev"  data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next"  data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
      </a>
    </div>

carouselSlider() {
    var self = this;
    this.slider = $(this.carousel);

    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000,
        pause: false
      })

      for (let j = 0; j < self.listOfImages.length; j++) {
        let image = self.listOfImages[j];
        $('<div class="carousel-item"><img src=' + image + ' width="50%">   </div>').appendTo('.carousel-inner');
        $('<li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="' + j + '"></li>').appendTo('.carousel-indicators')
      }

      $('.carousel-item').first().addClass('active');
      $('.carousel-indicators > li').first().addClass('active');

      $('a[data-slide="prev"]').click(function () {
        $(self.carousel).carousel('prev');
      });

      $('a[data-slide="next"]').click(function () {
        $(self.carousel).carousel('next');
      });

      self.slider.carousel();
    });
  }
```

and calling carouselSlider in the attached() function.